# How to printf a list of values?

Tags: c

When I `Enter` new values they should display in `View` as a list like

```
1. 1 2 3 4 5 //first values
2. 6 5 9 8 3 // second values
3. 4 2 3 8 5 // ...
```

but instead it prints just the first values to the whole list. I try to fix this wihout a 2d array if possible. Any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LENGTH 5
const char *menuMsg = "\n\n\t Menu \n\n\t v (View)\n\t e (Enter)\n\t q (Quit)\n";

int main(){
    int run = 1;
    while(run){
        puts(menuMsg);
        char choice;
        scanf(" %c", &choice);

        int x, z;
        int a[LENGTH];
        int list=6;

        if(choice=='e') {
            for(x=0; x<LENGTH; x++){
                printf("Enter nr.%d: ", x+1);
                scanf("%d", &a[x]);
            }
            z++;
        }
        else if(choice=='v') {
            for(z=0; z<list; z++){
                printf("\n%d. ", z+1);
                for(x=0; x<LENGTH; x++){
                    printf("%d ", a[x]);
                }
            }
        }
        else if(choice=='q') run = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `a[LENGTH]` only holds one row of data.  You should go ahead and use a 2-d array.

Answer (score 1):

The length of your array `a` is only 5. I'm concerned about where you define it since you expect it to print out 6 rows of 5 values- 30 individual numbers.

This might work, modify to your needs:

```
#define LENGTH 5 // amount in a row (number of cols)
#define HEIGHT 6 // amount of rows

a[LENGTH * HEIGHT] = { 0, 2, 3, 4...};

for (z=0; z < HEIGHT; z++){
   printf("\n%d. ", z+1);
   for (x=0; x < LENGTH; x++){
        printf("%d ", a[x + LENGTH*z]);
   }
}
```